# Analytics data via Script/Widget

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, widget

I have a webpage on one domain, and a blog on another. I am looking to build a script/widget for myself, which can track my blog's statistics (visitors, unique visitors, geography of visitor, etc) and send them over to my webpage where it can be displayed.

Is such a thing possible? If yes, could you please point me in the right direction? I'm new to widget programming, so i'm not entirely sure how to word my search.I am trying to learn, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've installed Google Anatytics [web tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs) on your blog, you should be able to build a dashboard to view charts of the usage data pretty easily using the new [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed).

The Embed API handles the hardest parts for you (authentication and converting the data to Google Chart format), so you can pretty easily display visualizations of your data without too much work.

Here are the Embed API docs:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed

And here is a demo site showing what you can build with the Embed API:
http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/demos/embed-api/

Comment: I have not installed it at the moment, I shall momentarily! I'm curious though, is it possible to do this without having web tracking installed?

Comment: Why don't you want to use web tracking? If you don't use web tracking you'll have to do the tracking manually yourself. I guess I'm not sure what your end goal is.

Comment: Ah its not that I don't, I was just interested to see if I could do without it. Basically I want to do minimal changes to the blog itself (I have some reasons for this), apart from including a script or two. Is this possible?

Comment: As an example, using the `Moz API` for tracking Moz Rank, Domain Authority, etc. with only a php class to be included. Something along those lines is what I am looking for, if possible. If not, I will make do with what you gave me :)

Comment: Adding Google Analytics is just one snippet. Any other solution would also require adding at least *something* to your blog, unless you did everything on the back-end (which I wouldn't recommend).